# How can a Python seaborn combo chart be separated our like a FacetGrid?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created a combo line chart with two y-axis that aggregates the data for both "models" (Blue widget and Green Widget). What I want to do is have two separate combo charts based on the values of the "model" column in "data1" dataframe (Chart 1 would be a combo chart to Blue widget and Chart 2 would be the combo chart for Green Widget, the order doesn't matter). How can this be done?

Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data1 = {'revenue': [345,543,434,678,456,544,356,765,566,434],
        'month': ['01-01-2020', '01-01-2020','01-01-2020','01-02-2020','01-02-2020','01-02-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-03-2020','01-03-2020'],
        'model': ['Blue Widget', 'Green Widget','Green Widget','Blue Widget','Blue Widget','Green Widget','Blue Widget','Blue Widget','Green Widget','Green Widget']}
data2 = {'AOV': [45,65,56,67,69,54,56,66,44,55],
        'month': ['01-01-2020', '01-01-2020','01-01-2020','01-02-2020','01-02-2020','01-02-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-03-2020','01-03-2020']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Here is the chart which needs to be separated out, similar to Facetgrid, based on the column for "model" in Data2:

```
#Create combo chart
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
color = 'tab:green'
#line plot1 creation
ax1.set_title('Revenue vs Average Order Value', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_xlabel('Day', fontsize=16)
ax1 = sns.lineplot(x='month', y='revenue', data = df1, ci=None)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y')
ax1.set_ylabel('Revenue', fontsize=16)
#specify we want to share the same x-axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
color = 'tab:red'
#line plot2 creation
ax2.set_ylabel('AOV', fontsize=16)
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x='month', y='AOV', data = df2, sort=False, color=color, ci=None)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', color=color)
#show plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, merge your two dataframes (I assume they match row-wise, otherwise figure out how to merge them as desired).

Then, you can create a custom plotting function to pass to `FacetGrid`:

```
def combo(*cols,**kwargs):
    df = kwargs.pop('data')
    color = kwargs.pop('color')
    colors = kwargs.pop('colors')
    ax1 = plt.gca()
    ax1 = sns.lineplot(x=cols[0], y=cols[1], data = df, ci=None, ax=ax1, color=colors[0], **kwargs)
    #specify we want to share the same x-axis
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax2 = sns.lineplot(x=cols[0], y=cols[2], data = df, sort=False, ci=None, ax=ax2, color=colors[1], **kwargs)

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df3, col='model')
g.map_dataframe(combo, 'month', 'revenue', 'AOV', colors=['tab:green', 'tab:red'])
```

[image]

Comment: So I just merged df1 and df2 as such:
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0).reset_index()

Then I copy pasted your code below it. It generated the charts but no lines on them like you were able to. What do you think I may have done wrong?